# How to use Get Request APi in futtter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

How to use get API request in a flutter, please help me I have a project about that. I tried many of times and many of codes write but don't solve issues

Comment: Did you check this article https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data ?

Answer (score 0):

at first add `http: ^0.13.0` to pubspec.yaml

add this to the class `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

must add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`  to the top of the AndroidMenifest file

```
Future<List<Post>> requestForData() async {
static var client = http.Client();
var response = await 
client.get(Uri.parse("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  var posts= response.body;
  return posts;
} else {
  return null;
}
}
```